# how to partial loading a very big picture from the internet?

Tags: android, image

i hava a problem ,i want to display a very long picture from the internet in the listView with Adapter,but it occured a problem :Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (600x4517, max=4096x4096).
if i add a statement like this:android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in the Manifest.xml,it can display,but the experience of the scrolling not well.
if i use BitmapFactory to compress image pixels ,it will make the picture fuzzy.
if i want to diaplay a picture without Image deformation,what can i do ?
I hava an idea,if i can  loading parts of the picture which it  can be visible?
the project use volley and Glide.Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Loading images for Android can be a hazardous process.

You are loading extremely large images. Android is notoriously bad at dealing with those. Commonly resulting in `OutOfMemoryError`s.

You would be well advised in reconsidering network loading massive images on your device. Especially in a `ListView`!

Additionally, it is good to use an established library for this kind of functionality. Such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Great Answer @Knossos I was facing the similar problem.Using Picasso I just solved my problem.Upvoting your answer.

Comment: can you tell some detail of how to use picasso to solve this problem?

Comment: There are a great many different examples of how to use Picasso on their website. You should look at their samples to see how best to integrate it into your App. I have added an example from their website.